# Can you activate and deactivate image detection in arkit using Unity UI features?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

Is it possible to turn image detection on and off inside an application using UI features from Unity? I want to be able to only use the image detection after selecting a toggle, but still be able to detect planes the entire time. When the toggle is deselected I want to be able to view the image through the camera with nothing happening, but still detect planes on the ground. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: I don't know about the Unity-SDK, but it is possible to 'restart' a session with a different configuration. As long as you don't specific to reset tracking and/ or features, you should be able to use different configurations with and without image tracking and switch between them.

Comment: Are you going to do your image tracking using ARWolrdTrackingConfiguration or ARimageTrackingConfiguration.

Comment: I'm not writing it in swift, but I'm using the Generate Image Anchor script attached to an otherwise empty game object along with my ARReferenceImagesSet attached under the image tracking section of the Unity AR Camera Manager